# Error: tomEE required to support EAR/EJB deployment error message

Tags: spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I'm attempting to configure a spring MVC app so it builds a war file when the application is deployed. When I add the `examqa:war` artifact, I get the following error message (seen at the bottom of image)

[image: Run/debug config]

Not sure where to look, didn't find any mention of this error when using google. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi! Any news about that? I got the same issue :(

Comment: I've added an answer to how I solved this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot to change the `artifactId` and `name` in my pom.xml file from a previous setting.

```
<artifactId>examqa</artifactId>
<name>ExamQA</name>
```

Answer (score 8):

I got the same problem but solution was different. The problem was with artifact type which had to be changed from Java EE Application exploded to Web Application:Exploded/Archive

Answer (score 1):

I changed artifact type from EAR to WAR (deleted the old one and created a new one). This solved the problem.
In intellij, this can be done by going to artifacts in project-structure (alt+ctrl+shift+s).